# Unity, Android: a lot of crashes on devices with PowerVR GPU

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Unity 2020.3.41. The problematic GPU models are GE8320, GE8322 and GE8100. The most crashable devices are Xiaomi Redmi 6A, Redmi 9C, Redmi 9A, realme C21.

Some stacktraces:

1 (Google Play Console):

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.fruitshake.fairyrpg <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x0000000002691b1c  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #01  pc 0x0000000000dbe585  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #02  pc 0x000000000327bfc5  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #03  pc 0x0000000002e02caf  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #04  pc 0x0000000002e384ed  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #05  pc 0x0000000002e387c7  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #06  pc 0x0000000002e4c1db  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #07  pc 0x0000000002e4c18d  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #08  pc 0x0000000002e4c147  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #09  pc 0x0000000001db285f  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #10  pc 0x0000000000dc5969  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #11  pc 0x0000000000dc5ab5  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #12  pc 0x0000000001db285f  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #13  pc 0x0000000000dc5d87  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #14  pc 0x0000000000dc61e7  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #15  pc 0x0000000000dbd899  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #16  pc 0x0000000000dbca73  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #17  pc 0x0000000000dc267b  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #18  pc 0x0000000000db7983  /data/app/~~glJ5zj2YuTXCLtOwQQBW9Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_530409130-5JNvmPvdeqWxll114AWxEQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  #19  pc 0x00000000000024cd  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so (android::(anonymous namespace)::draw_gl(int, void*, android::uirenderer::DrawGlInfo const&)+228)
  #20  pc 0x0000000000160b13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WebViewFunctor::drawGl(android::uirenderer::DrawGlInfo const&)+34)
  #21  pc 0x0000000000142539  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::GLFunctorDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+1720)
  #22  pc 0x00000000001b8401  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+44)
  #23  pc 0x00000000003e0c2f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkGpuDevice::drawDrawable(SkDrawable*, SkMatrix const*, SkCanvas*)+206)
  #24  pc 0x0000000000113cb9  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1020)
  #25  pc 0x0000000000114523  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+198)
  #26  pc 0x000000000012a249  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::$_24::__invoke(void const*, SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const&)+44)
  #27  pc 0x0000000000113ced  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1072)
  #28  pc 0x0000000000114523  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+198)
  #29  pc 0x000000000012a249  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::$_24::__invoke(void const*, SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const&)+44)
  #30  pc 0x0000000000113cd5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1048)
  #31  pc 0x0000000000114523  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+198)
  #32  pc 0x000000000012a249  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::$_24::__invoke(void const*, SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const&)+44)
  #33  pc 0x0000000000113ced  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1072)
  #34  pc 0x0000000000114523  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+198)
  #35  pc 0x000000000012a249  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::$_24::__invoke(void const*, SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const&)+44)
  #36  pc 0x0000000000113cd5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1048)
  #37  pc 0x0000000000114523  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+198)
  #38  pc 0x000000000012a249  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::$_24::__invoke(void const*, SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const&)+44)
  #39  pc 0x0000000000113ced  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1072)
  #40  pc 0x0000000000114523  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+198)
  #41  pc 0x000000000012a249  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::$_24::__invoke(void const*, SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const&)+44)
  #42  pc 0x0000000000113cd5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1048)
  #43  pc 0x0000000000114523  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+198)
  #44  pc 0x00000000001475c7  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrameImpl(SkRect const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode> > > const&, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const&)+474)
  #45  pc 0x00000000001472df  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrame(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode> > > const&, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, sk_sp<SkSurface>, SkMatrix const&)+94)
  #46  pc 0x00000000001451bd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::draw(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::LightGeometry const&, android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue*, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, bool, android::uirenderer::LightInfo const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode> > > const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfoVisualizer*)+272)
  #47  pc 0x000000000014bb11  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+976)
  #48  pc 0x000000000014d3db  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+458)
  #49  pc 0x000000000014059f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+162)
  #50  pc 0x00000000001573b9  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+72)
  #51  pc 0x000000000000ee95  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+168)
  #52  pc 0x000000000000e9dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+256)
  #53  pc 0x00000000000aacf3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+40)
  #54  pc 0x0000000000064063  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
```

2 (Firebase):

```
Crashed: Thread: SIGSEGV  0x0000000000000000
#00 pc 0x142bb0 libGLESv2_mtk.so 
#01 pc 0x854d5 libGLESv2_mtk.so 
#02 pc 0x3222a libGLESv2_mtk.so 
#03 pc 0x27a44 libGLESv2_mtk.so 
#04 pc 0x2e861 libGLESv2_mtk.so 
#05 pc 0xbb2b2 libc.so
```

I know that the stacktraces are very obscure but I have no idea on how to make them more readable. I have uploaded my app's symbols to Firebase and Google Play.

There's a similar [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/there-is-a-bug-and-the-crash-in-libglesv2_mtk-so-on-some-devices.1262033) on Unity's forum.

If you have any idea on how to solve or research the issue, please help!

Answer (score 0):

It's solvable via drawing 1x1px (this helped me, at least) rectangle with different color every frame. As described in Unity's thread:

> florianpenzkofer: The root cause is a bug in the PowerVR driver where draw calls that the driver optimizes out leak some memory. That memory bufffer has a fixed size per framebuffer (RenderTexture) and running out of that memory causes the crash. A single draw call that is not optimized out reclaims the leaked memory, so this only leads to a problem if all draws to the same framebuffer (across multiple frames) are redundant.

Driver can't optimize this "random" draw call every frame.
Second option is to create native render plugin, there's example plugin at unity's repo. You'll need to cull glFlush, as stated in previous answer:

> In our experiments it helps to call glFinish roughly every 1000 frames (or more often but it‘s expensive because it stalls the GPU).
> You could try that using a native rendering plugin.
> We got some more information about when affected drivers leak some memory that causes this. We will look into that to maybe come up with a better workaround.

Comment: Hi Alex! Thanks for the info! Could you please elaborate more on the fix with the texture? Please, share your script.

Comment: BTW, I tried doing GL.Flush every frame as BBO_Lagoon suggested in the post. It didn't help to reduce crashes. Does GL.Flush or GL.Finish has any difference for this issue?

Comment: I haven't saved it, but it's basically material.color = random_color; commandBuffer.drawMesh(quad, material); and shader which sets the quad to screen corner with 1x1 or 2x2 pixels size (you can use _ScreenParams for it)

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how you did solve it with this 1x1 rectangle?

Comment: I have tried the glFlush and glFinish options, and it does NOT solve this. I'm highly skeptical of the 1x1px color option, but I'm willing to give it a try in a test if there was a clear code example provided. Having the code that @Alex says actually helped their situation would make this a potential complete answer. As is, it is not a complete answer, and I remain very skeptical.

Comment: @Alex can you please provide code sample of the 1x1px solution? This issue is still present for alot of users.